# How to output to a TexBox directly using RadioButtons and CheckBoxes without clicking Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how to output to a `TextBox` as soon as a user has clicked on a series of `RadioButtons` and clicked the `CheckBox`(es) which are found inside various `GroupBoxes` on the `Form`.

Any help will be really appreciated, in case this question has already been answered in the past let me know I have search for it but could not find anything like this.

Sample `Form` layout:

[image]

Comment: Radioboxes and checkboxes have events triggered when you check them that you can use, but your question is not clear.

Comment: Controls have events, like "Changed", and "Checked", etc. These are conceptually no different than the Click event of a button that you seem to know how to use already. Subscribe to the appropriate event and do what you would normally do with a button.

Comment: Is your application WPF or Windows Forms? If it is so, radio button has RadioButton_Checked event. You can try to write code there.

Comment: @CetinBasoz [link](https://imgur.com/a/mqLCfQt) this is what i need, and this is what i have done so far [link](https://imgur.com/a/Y3meQQy), i'm in the dark, help me out. I don't know if i am doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no good at chasing the pictures and especially code as picture doesn't help anyone. Anyway next time please don't do that.

First, for all of your radio and checkboxes (radChocolate, radVanilla, ... radSmall, ..., chkChocoChips, ...) double click and fill Checked event such as:

```
private void radChocolate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculatePrice();
}
private void radVanilla_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculatePrice();
}
// Do the same for other radio and checkboxes
```

Then add the CalculatePrice code as such (prices are arbitrary):

```
private void CalculatePrice()
{
    decimal price = 0M;
    if (radChocolate.Checked) price += 75M;
    if (radVanilla.Checked) price += 65M;
    if (radStrawberry.Checked) price += 55M;

    if (radSmall.Checked) price += 20M;
    if (radLarge.Checked) price += 30M;

    if (chkChocoChips.Checked) price += 5M;
    if (chkCookieCandy.Checked) price += 4M;
    if (chkNuts.Checked) price += 3M;
    if (chkFreshFruits.Checked) price += 2M;

    txtPrice.Text = price.ToString("C");
}
```

This would do what you wanted to.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far. I modified the code a little bit and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/DXcaEi6) This is the part I modified. I was asked to use double data type for this lol, even though decimal seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Tim, when it is money, IMHO it is a bad idea to use double. Double is not exact while decimal is.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your link, you can create one event handler and bind it to all the events. ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-connect-multiple-events-to-a-single-event-handler-in-windows-forms) explaining binding)

So, every time any value is changed in your form, only one function gets called.
Then, check the values of every component present in your form and calculate value of your textbox.

Comment: What does winforms have to do with JavaScript? or AutoPostBack?

Comment: My bad, did not read about it that it was related to WindowsForms. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Nishant Please read the above response, i have posted links to the problem and what i have done so far.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you debug and tell if you are facing issue with setting textbox value or calculating the value?

Comment: @Nishant I have to read more about the binding multiple event handlers later, thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create an event handler for each radio button, or create a single event handler for all the radio buttons. It would depend on what you are trying to accomplish. For the radio button you would want to subscribe to the `CheckedChanged` event. Then inside this event you can change the text box.

```
private void radioButtonChangeText_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here to change text box or call sub
    textBox.Text = "Hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a radio button and the go to properties, there click on "events" (that lightning sign). There is an event there called "CheckedChanged". Double click on the cell next to it to generate the event method.
it will generate a code like this,

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi there");
    }
```

you should be able to put any thing you want in there. Assuming you want to show hide the TextBox, you can do it in there.

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setCheckBoxValue();   
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setCheckBoxValue();
    }

    private void setCheckBoxValue()
    {
        int finalPrice = 0;
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            finalPrice = finalPrice + 75;
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            finalPrice = finalPrice + 87;
        }

        textBox1.Text = finalPrice.ToString("C");            
    }
```

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/mqLCfQt) here is what i need to do. Here is what i did [link](https://imgur.com/a/Y3meQQy).

Comment: Sorry I checked. Your code looks fine to me. 
Its just that, using if(chocoletchips && ...) type of code will make it redundent.
Heres an idea, create a seporate method someMethod();  to recalculate everyting. Call that method from inside each event.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, and report if I faced any problem. I was using the if statements to get the an idea of how should I proceed.